# httpOnly Presisting Authentication token status between DRF and reactJS

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux, httponly, cookie-httponly

I seem to be having trouble persisting my athntication status between django and reactjs ( when i refresh the page ) i loose authentication.
upon sending requests to my endpoints in postman with my access_token everything is working great.

Here is how my drf is setup
Settings.py

```
# CORS settings

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

# CSRF settings
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "None"
```

views.py

```
class CookieTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        if response.data.get("access"):
            response.set_cookie(
                "access_token",
                response.data["access"],
                httponly=True,
                secure=False,
                samesite="Lax",
            )
            del response.data["access"]
        return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)


class CookieTokenRefreshView(TokenRefreshView):
    def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
        if response.data.get("access"):
            response.set_cookie(
                "access_token",
                response.data["access"],
                httponly=True,
                secure=False,
                samesite="Lax",
            )
            del response.data["access"]
        return super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)


@api_view(["GET"])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def check_auth_status(request):
    # If the request reaches here, the user is authenticated
    return Response({"status": "authenticated"})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("api/token/", CookieTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair"),
    path("api/token/refresh/", CookieTokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="token_refresh"),
    path("api/check_auth_status/", check_auth_status, name="check_auth_status"),
    path("api/", include("vessels.urls")),
]
```

frontend side
authslice.js

```
export const verifyAuth = createAsyncThunk(
  "auth/verifyAuth",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      await api.get("/api/check_auth_status/");
      // If the request is successful, the user is authenticated
      return true;
    } catch (error) {
      // If there is an error (like a 401), the user is not authenticated
      return rejectWithValue(false);
    }
  }
);

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    // other states...
  },
  reducers: {
    // ... your other reducers ...
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(verifyAuth.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
      })
      .addCase(verifyAuth.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
      });
  },
});

export const { loginSuccess, logout } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

loginpage.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import api from "../../api/axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { TextField, Button, Paper, Typography, Box } from "@mui/material";
import { verifyAuth } from "../../redux/slices/authSlice";
function LoginPage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      await api.post("api/token/", { username, password });

      // Verify authentication status
      dispatch(verifyAuth()).then(() => {
        // Redirect after successful login
        navigate("/");
      });
    } catch (error) {
      setError("Invalid credentials");
      console.error("Login error", error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      minHeight="100vh"
    >
      <Paper elevation={3} style={{ padding: "20px", width: "300px" }}>
        <Typography variant="h5" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          Login
        </Typography>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextField
            label="Username"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            margin="normal"
            value={username}
            onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
          />
          <TextField
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            margin="normal"
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            fullWidth
            style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
          >
            Login
          </Button>
          {error && (
            <Typography color="error" style={{ marginTop: "20px" }}>
              {error}
            </Typography>
          )}
        </form>
      </Paper>
    </Box>
  );
}

export default LoginPage;
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(verifyAuth());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <ProtectedRoute>
              <HomePage />
            </ProtectedRoute>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

and finally ProtectedRoute.js

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = useSelector((state) => state.auth.isAuthenticated);
  const location = useLocation();

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }

  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Comment: Are you *actually* losing authentication to the backend, or is it just that the `isAuthenticated` state is reset when you reload the page and you are bounced off the protected route back to `"/login"`? Does the `dispatch(verifyAuth());` in `App` reestablish the correct `isAuthenticated state after the app mounts? Can you clarify in a bit more detail what exactly the issue or problem is that you are observing?

Comment: @DrewReese The app is running as it suppose to , when i got to "/" it redirects to login page because i am not authenticated, once i log in, i am auth and everything is fine and i can go to any protectedroute just as it suppose to. just once i hit the F5 button (refresh the page) i loose my authentication. so i am trying to persist it by a check status but i am just not to sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is the case that you are losing the authentication. I suspect that the `isAuthenticated` state is reinitialized to `false` when the page is reloaded and your `ProtectedRoute` component selects that initial state value and renders the redirect back to the login page.

A trivial solution is to persist the auth state to localStorage and initialize the auth state from localStorage.

Example:

```js
export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    isAuthenticated: !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authenticated")),
    // other states...
  },
  reducers: {
    // ... your other reducers ...
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(verifyAuth.fulfilled, (state) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        localStorage.setItem("authenticated", true);
      })
      .addCase(verifyAuth.rejected, (state) => {
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        localStorage.setItem("authenticated", false);
      });
  },
});
```

Now when the page reloads, the persisted `isAuthenticated` state will be reinitialized and the user should stay on the protected route they were on. The dispatched `verifyAuth` action when the app mounts may invalidate their authentication later.